# How can I count the rows of a CSV with only the linux terminal?

Tags: linux, csv

I have a CSV with 32 fields, one of them is XMLContent and the value for that field is a XML. I want to count just the 3500+ rows in the csv, i can't use the "wc -l" because  i get the total lines including all the lines in the XML and the result it's over 5,000,000...Thanks for your help!

Comment: export the csv from postgres w/o the XML field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with [Miller](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html) (here the precompiled [binary for linux](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/releases/download/5.4.0/mlr.linux.x86_64))

```
mlr --csv --headerless-csv-output cat -n then stats1 -a max -f n input.csv
```

The output is what you want

Comment: it's in a server. I can't install any package.

Comment: @RaulEduardo it's a binary: simply download it in your csv folder (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/releases/download/5.4.0/mlr.linux.x86_64), rename it in mlr and give it execute permission. 
Then run "./mlr --csv --headerless-csv-output cat -n then stats1 -a max -f n input.csv"

Comment: I found another way: cat -A file.csv | grep -v '\^M' | wc -l